Prevent background SQL process TEMPORAL_HK_FLUS from starting
I'm having a problem when running a number of SQL scripts on a database in a single_user mode. I have found a way to solve most of my problems regarding background processes but now I'm stuck on a background process that runs what sp_Who2 calls "TEMPORAL_HK_FLUS". It appears to have to do with cleaning rows from temporal history tables (that i don't use) and/or a "Data Flush Task" and I can't find a way to prevent this background process from starting.
Any suggestions and help is appreciated.
And. Yes. I know. Running SQL scripts and such on a database in a single_user mode is not recommended and it is not what I want to do. But I'm a bit stuck with what I inherited now and need to solve this. If not, it will cause a lot of work for me and my coworkers.
I have searched internet, consulted all SQL server documentation that I can find and search in and even asked ChatGTP. But no luck yet

So, you have a database that is in single user mode only, but you still want to run some queries in it, but sometimes some other internal processes is highjacking the single user mode and you can't run stuff there, is that the issue? What horrible terrible thing will happen if you change the database to MULTI_USER?

The question is not "why I can't run in multi_user mode". It will take precious time from me and other if I try to explain the whole situation. The simple answer is that I can't without doing a heavy coding to change the whole construction of an oldy system.

Ok, and you can't keep a connection open so it blocks the other stuff?

That's not working. Keeping the connection open is not blocking background processes. Therefore I e.g. have to run "alter database [xxx] set auto_create_statistics off" etc to stop those background processes to get in the way
